# Calculating difference between dates with amDifference filter

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xFJ8NF?p=preview)**

I have a questions about using the amDifference filter in angular-moment.

Currently I have it set up like this:

```
{{order.shipDate | amDifference: null: 'days'}}
```

Which is calculating the difference between the ship date and the current date, but it is backwards with what I need if for. For example, if my shipDate was on 12/05/2015 it is currently showing '-81', but I would like for it to show '81'. So I guess something like this:

```
{{currentDate | amDifference: order.shipDate: 'days'}}
```

I have already tried this:

```
{{null | amDifference: order.shipDate: 'days'}}
```

Which didn't work.

So I guess I want to know:

1. Am I using the right angular-moment filter?
2. If I can use this filter, how do I accomplish it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: why can't you reverse the comparison values the way second version is shown? Create a demo that can be forked and tested with

Comment: @charlietfl When I reverse nothing shows up. I will create a demo and post it.

Comment: create a demo using plunker or fiddle or jsbin to show, that will be really helpful for you as well as to them seeking to help you.

Comment: @charlietfl Here is the link to the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/xFJ8NF?p=preview

Comment: Those aren't valid date strings ... try `new Date('2015-06-19T03:15:26 +04:00')` in browser console. Also note the warning thrown by `moment` in console

Comment: Seems to work fine with valid input strings

Comment: @charlietfl The dates are showing as MM/DD/YYYY in my app because I used amDateFormat:'MM/DD/YYYY'.... they are not showing in the plunkr for some reason.

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the plunkr.... now the dates are showing correctly. https://plnkr.co/edit/xFJ8NF?p=preview

Comment: Seems to work fine here using valid ISO strings. The only negative value is when ship occurs before order which isn't reality https://plnkr.co/edit/6zclmm?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, but that is not exactly my problem. You are showing the difference between the two dates. I want the difference between the shipDate and today. Is that possible with how I have it set up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set a variable for `today` in controller

```
$scope.today = new Date();
```

Then do

```
<td>{{ today | amDifference:  order.shipDate : 'days'}} days</td>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Asv4i5?p=preview)**</kbd>